# Importing email to IMAP mailbox

Tags: php, email, imap

I am able to retrieve e-mails from a single mailbox with PHP and store them into a database. Though I want to have the option to "restore" the message back to the database.

My collegue told me I should take a look at the `imap_append()` function which comes with PHP. Though there are just a very few examples available.

I'm not sure about which fields I need to insert to always make sure the message gets "restored" correct. I have like all fields from the e-mail in my database (but if needed I can add extra fields).

My question; which fields should EVERY e-mail contain and is anyone able to give me an example of how I could do this (`imap_append()` or ...?)

Answer (score 0):

Append only takes two parameters: the `INTERNALDATE`, and the `FLAGS`.  Everything else is contained within the message itself.  You can get the date and flags from the original message.  Or, you can fake it by reading out the date header and using it as the internaldate.

Comment: I can read almost all fields from the original message, but isen't there any way how I can (maybe even fetch the original message as a package) and just "restore" it by uploading the package somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Read about the [APPEND Command](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.3.11) in the [IMAP RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501). Quoting it:

```
6.3.11. APPEND Command

   Arguments:  mailbox name
               OPTIONAL flag parenthesized list
               OPTIONAL date/time string
               message literal
```

You don't have to worry about the option arguments. The important things to consider are the mailbox name (folder to which you're uploading the message) and the message literal (the message itself). The message itself is the MIME data that includes all the header fields, so you really don't need to worry about those. You only need to make sure that you have the entire message data stored in your database, so you can restore the full message.

I've never used IMAP with PHP, but I've looked at the [imap_append()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-append.php) command you were talking about, and it does have arguments corresponding to what I've just explained - they are $mailbox and $message. In $mailbox you put the name of the folder (e.g. "INBOX"), and the message data to restore goes into $message.